# For loop and complexity in game of life

Tags: c, time-complexity, conways-game-of-life

While trying to optimize the performances of a code in C ( 4 glider guns, one in each corner in game of life ) , I had to choose between two scenarios :

```
int M = (int) DIM / 2 + 1;
for (int y = 1; y < M; y += TILE_SIZE)
  for (int x = 1; x < M; x += TILE_SIZE)
  {
    change |= do_tile(x, y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, omp_get_thread_num());
    change |= do_tile(DIM - x, y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, omp_get_thread_num());
    change |= do_tile(x, DIM - y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, omp_get_thread_num());
    change |= do_tile(DIM - x, DIM - y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, omp_get_thread_num());
  }
```

and

```
for (int y = 1; y < DIM - 1; y += TILE_SIZE)
  for (int x = 1; x < DIM - 1; x += TILE_SIZE)
    change |= do_tile(x, y, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, omp_get_thread_num());
```

If we think of it in a complexity way we get that both of them have the same time complexity:

(DIM/2) * (DIM/2) * 4 = DIM * DIM

but when I execute them the first one always finishes in less than 600ms while the second one finishes in around 650ms. How is that possible ? Is there any better optimization for this configuration of game of life ?

Comment: The first one has a much different memory access pattern from the second one. Likely, the second one makes much more effective use of cache.

Comment: Complexity gives an estimate, and measures what happens as the input grows. Fine-grained performance needs to be evaluated on actual programs.
On why, because loop unrolling (that's what you're doing) means fewer jumps, and the processor doesn't like jumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Oppen said above, the complexity that I gave is just an estimate ( O(DIM * DIM) 
). And since processors are not fond of jumps which are inside the loop, so less iterations mean less time.